# How is 1-bit bitmap data converted to 8bit (24bpp)?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, colors

Supposing I have 4 bitmaps, say, CMYK, all of which are 1bit/pixel and are of different colors, and I wanted to convert them to an 8bit/color (24bpp) bitmap, how would I do this?

if the data looks like this:

```
// the Cyan separation

CCCC CCCC CCCC CCCC CCCC CCCC CCCC CCCC
...

// the magenta separation, and so on..
MMMM MMMM MMMM MMMM MMMM MMMM MMMM MMMM
...
```

Say, the Cyan had an RGB value of (0,255,255), and at Pixel 0 (first pixel), I had a value of 1 (on), and the Magenta had an RGB value of (255,255,0), and at the same pixel, had a value of 1.. What would the first RGB pixel look like? Would it look like this?

```
BBBB BBBB GGGG GGGG RRRR RRRR
// would this 3-byte sequence  actually be 255,255,255
// because the cyan has (0,255,255) and the 
// magenta has (255,255,0)?
```

Thanks, just confused as to how to convert 1bit separations into an 8bit image.. Thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CMYK is a substractive color system, while RGB is an additive one.

If you have a CMY(K) value of (1.0, 1.0, 1.0), it's black, while an RGB value of (255, 255, 255), it's white.

Cyan + Magenta = Blue: (0, 255, 255) + (255, 0, 255) != (0, 0, 255). But not exactly, because we're talking different color systems.

You need to first construct the pixels in CMYK, and then convert them to RGB, which can be *approximated* by doing `(R, G, B) = (1-C, 1-M, 1-Y)`.

In order to convert a 1-bit value to an 8-bit value, you just need to transform every `0` into `0x00` and every `1` into `0xFF`: Multiply `bitValue` by `0xFF`.

Comment: Right, I completely forgot.. So when you say that I have to construct the pixels in CMYK, does that mean it would be something like 4-bit indexed colour? (CMYK) = (1,1,1,1).. and so on? Anyway, this is quite helpful, thanks.. Marking this as the answer..

Comment: Yes, you need to build the 4-tuple of colors. The problem, as I said, is converting CMYK to RGB, since there's no standard way, as @danben said. _Perhaps_ `(R,G,B) = ((1-C)(1-K), (1-M)(1-K), (1-Y)(1-K))`.

Comment: Right, thanks.. :) an approximation is good enough, I only need the RGB to display on an RGB device (monitor).. Thanks again :)

Comment: BTW, in that last formula you gave, since the values for CMYK can only be 1 or 0 (1-bit), if either C or K is 1, then the R part would be 0?

Answer (score 3):

Practically, with 1-bit coded CMYK you have 16 possible combinations (colors), 9 of which are black.

```
xxx1 -- black (8 comb's) -- 0x000000
0000 -- white -- 0xFFFFFF
1000 -- cyan -- 0x00FFFF
0100 -- magenta -- 0xFF00FF
0010 -- yellow -- 0xFFFF00
1100 -- blue -- 0x0000FF
1010 -- green -- 0x00FF00
0110 -- red -- 0xFF0000
1110 -- black -- 0x000000
```

Given this, I'd rather go with a mapping (switch-case or if-elses) than an actual algorithm for calculating RGB from CMYK. Of course, return early if K is set.