# image conversion

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing

I need to convert a RGB (jpg) grayscale CMYK using only to black channel (K).

I'm trying to do this with imageglue, but the result is not what i'm looking for since it converts the grays using the C,M and Y channel and leaves the black channel to 0%.

What I need is if anyone has experience in using any other library/api in .net that could work?

Comment: What are you *really* trying to accomplish?

Comment: "RGB (jpg) grayscale CMYK" is confusing? What is your image actually? RGB or CMYK?

Answer (score 2):

I would start by looking at the ColorConvertedBitmap class in WPF. Here is a link to the docs and a basic example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.colorconvertedbitmap(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you [triedAForge.Net](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/)?

There is also ImageMagick, a c++ framework for image processing, with a .net wrapper (google for MagickNet)

Answer (score 0):

Her is [RGB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model) to/from [CMYK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK_color_model) question which is related this one:

[How is 1-bit bitmap data converted to 8bit (24bpp)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003643/how-is-1-bit-bitmap-data-converted-to-8bit-24bpp)

Answer (score 0):

I found The [bitmap transform classes](http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/wpf-workings/678-the-bitmap-transform-classes.html) useful when trying to do some image format conversions but ... CYMK is one of the most complicated conversions you can tackle because there is more than one way to represent some colours. In particular equal CYM percentages give you shades of grey which are equivalent to the same percentage of K. Printers often use undercolour removal/transformation which normalises CYMK so that the a large common percentage is taken from CYM and transfered to the K. This is suppose to give purer blacks and grey tones. So even if you have a greyscale image represented using nothing but CYM with a zero black channel it could still print using nothing but K when you get it to a printer using undercolour removal.